# NPM Error - App-framewrk installation

Tags: macos, npm, html-framework-7, appframework

I tried to install the framework7 app - framework [app-framework github](https://github.com/scriptPilot/app-framework#app-framework------) . But got this error

`npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/package.json'
npm WARN user No description
npm WARN user No repository field.
npm WARN user No README data
npm WARN user No license field.`

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `package.json` file  with these informations :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "app-framework": "*"
  }
}
```

Cf. [project setup](https://github.com/scriptPilot/app-framework/blob/master/docs/setup.md)